# SQLite connecting to VB.net

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, visual-studio-2013

I have an application in VB.net and im trying to connect it to SQLite.
I am ecnountering this error.

```
The thread 0x1cb4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
'WindowsApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WindowsApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'c:\users\eramo7176736\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\bin\Debug\WindowsApplication1.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'WindowsApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WindowsApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Remoting\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Additional information: Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.
```

This is my code trying to open connnection

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sqlconnect As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection()
        Dim sqlcommand As SQLite.SQLiteCommand

        sqlconnect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\sqlite\test.db;"
        sqlconnect.Open()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is my system information: 
[image]

Windows 7 Enterprise, 64bit
I have also added `System.Data.SQLite.DLL` as project reference.

Comment: why not get 2015?

Comment: If you added it manually you may have referenced a build for a different NET version. Use NuGet and it adds the right one

Comment: you're saying that if i get 2015 and repeat the same procedure it will work?

Comment: can u write up an answer on how i can use nuget?

Comment: its okay now, i just use this `Install-Package System.Data.SQLite`